# Firmar comprobante electrónico XML con certificado digital

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy construyendo un comprobante de pago electrónico en XML de acuerdo a los requisitos de SUNAT en Perú y uno de los tags es la firma (signature) según el UBL 2.1. Tengo el certificado de la empresa pero no se cómo firmar el comprobante, es decir como definir el valor de signature con el certificado digital.

```
<SignatureValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">ChCm648ggeOeffL2Ne9exEvIWAnFgTGgsDLFtolPv5WA42ToWsvVIcFqpNtQTMMz1jr9IJbHCg73KWUMz3L/iOu6IrfWoKOJyCkgyfw6/1mWyamQV3NudOC3/SQjMpYmFJ3LVr+aGmXEg5+E1akHfs55Eu+OMcvwmW+gJLpd27j4MKcYE+kNu7XcXwdIUuufgRQgrXzXC+tJU1MURnsNqQXVZgJ/LELSRvwG3Lx6r2+g7Wgacd5zwP9ZVth/stSxKcJ7Kw3ZWX0B6xzbESFAJI6kUd3zQFT3vgLtiW5n2PlzgbK9Muw8ddnc68AYzincHnMbE1xMF2+Uvq+dgWbMCw==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><X509Data><X509SubjectName>C=PE, CN=MELISSA WENDY PONTE NARCIZO, G=MELISSA WENDY, SN=PONTE NARCIZO, T=ASISTENTA CONTABLE, OU=20112316238, OU=CONTABILIDAD, O=EDUARDO FAJARDO GUTIERREZ., OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.17326.30.4=DNI, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.17326.30.3=20112316238, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.17326.30.2=RUC, SERIALNUMBER=70275816, S=LIMA-LIMA, L=LIMA, Description=Qualified Certificate: RACER-PFVP-SW-KPSC, E=efajardo@codesisac.com</X509SubjectName><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
```

Conocen alguna clase en C# que genere este valor? Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: No se si esto es lo que buscas: [Procedimiento Firmar documentos XML con firmas digitales](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures). Saludos

Comment: También te puede ayudar este blog: [Interoperable XML Digital Signatures (C#-Java), part 1](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c.html) y la segunda parte: [Interoperable XML Digital Signatures (C#-Java), part 2](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c_20.html). Está en inglés, pero creo que se entiende bastante bien. Saludos